# Casting Control to TextBlock in a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, textblock

I have a set of `TextBlocks` inside a `Grid` that I would like to be able to programatically access their `.Text` properties. There are also `Buttons` and `Images` inside the `Grid`, so I've done some validation like so;

```
foreach (Control control in navButtonGrid.Children)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
    {
        //TextBlock.Text here
    }
}
```

In doing this I get an error,

> Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control' to
>   'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' via a reference conversion, boxing
>   conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type
>   conversion

How am I able to correctly cast my `Control` so that I can access only the `TextBlocks` in the `Grid`?

**FINAL EDIT:** I have all of the `TextBlock.Text` inside the `Buttons` being named, however they are all the same `Text`. This is my implementation;

```
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in navButtonDT.Rows)
{
    foreach (UIElement control in navButtonGrid.Children)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
        {
            TextBlock tb = ((control as Button).Content as StackPanel).Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();
            tb.Text = navButtonDT.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

If I do this all the `TextBlocks` take the `string` value of the last `DataRow`. What I would like is that `TextBlock1.Text = row1`, `TextBlock2.Text = row2` etc etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `OfType` like this:

```
foreach (var control in navButtonGrid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
{
    //Do your stuff with control      
}
```

Or you could replace the `Control` with **`var`** or **`UIElement`** in `foreach`:

```
foreach (var control in navButtonGrid.Children)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
    {
         TextBlock tb = control as TextBlock;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (UIElement control in navButtonGrid.Children)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
    {
        TextBlock tb = control as TextBlock;
    }
}
```

EDIT: To find a `TextBlock` inside a Button you could do like this:

```
else if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
{
    TextBlock tb = ((control as Button).Content as StackPanel).Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: @almost there! Thanks for all your help.. could you see my final edit?

Comment: @CBreeze...Move the `i++;` to your `if` statement.

Comment: Just worked it out before your comment, thanks for your help!